# Binary logistic regression vs generalized estimating equation (GEE) for time series

Tags: time-series, logistic, autocorrelation, generalized-estimating-equations

I have time series with 322 observations. My dataset contains financial data. My endogenous variable, "target" is a binary variable. My exogenous variables are two continuous variables: "market_return" and "retail_reduction_rate" and one binary variable "target_lag1" which is lagged dependent variable. The reason for that is that I found out that my dependent variable is autocorrelated up to first 7 lags using the Ljung-Box test. Here's the output from my function for performing the Ljung-Box test: [image]

Firstly I created simple binary logistic regression model. Here's the output:[image]

Surprisingly, deviance residuals aren't correlated at all. Here's the output from my function for performing the Ljung-Box test:
[image]

I'm not sure if that is evidence that observations are independent (this is one of the critical assumptions in logistic regression).

I know that GEE model address the serial correlation in data, so I tried utilizing it. I defined a first-order autoregressive working dependence structure (I used PACF and confirmed that only first lag is significantly different from zero), covariance type as robust and I treated all observations as one cluster. Here's the output:
[image]

It's very different from Logit Regression Results. Standard errors are much smaller!

Bonus: Here's the output for the 'naive' covariance type:

[image]

Which approach is correct?